# double if conditioning in r language syntax

Tags: r

What is the correct way of writing if syntax on R?

With:

```
for ( i in 1:200 ) {
     if( (time[i]<731) | (time[i]==NA) ) { x[i] <- NA }
}
```

I keep getting:

```
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

The idea is to cut the beginning of the time series to calculate statistics. `x` and `time` are both numeric. Also this question is not an exact duplicate, the other post was dealing with a && statement and no foo==NA but foo==0. I thought that | or || would work like (TRUE | NA) = TRUE but it seems I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't write things like `if (foo==NA)` because comparing anything with `NA` returns `NA`.
Instead, try

```
if( is.na(foo))
```

Comment: @joran very gracious to delete your response -I thought you beat me to it.

Comment: <shrug> Yours was already there when I hit submit. Joshua found a good duplicate anyway.

Comment: if( (time[i]<731) | is.na(time[i]) ) { x[i] <- NA } works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
is.na(x) <- (time < 731 | is.na(time))
```

Comment: this doesn't work, all it does is make x full of NA from beginning to end.

Comment: @user3083324 There was a typo. Try the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted:

```
> n = 10
> x <- rep(0, n)
> time <- rpois(n, 731)
> 
> for ( i in 1:n ) {
+   if( time[i] < 731 | is.na(time[i])) {  
+     x[i] <- NA
+   } 
+ }
> x
 [1]  0  0 NA NA NA  0 NA NA  0  0
```

You can do:

```
> ifelse(time < 731 | is.na(time[i]),  NA, x)
 [1]  0  0 NA NA NA  0 NA NA  0  0
```